# How can I add '%' to my select of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I want to get count of one table, also I want to show list of `GeoID`. The problem is I can't add '%' to my where

```
SELECT        
    GeoTitle AS Expr1,GeoId , (GeoId+'%') as moh,
    (SELECT       
         COUNT(Product.ProductId)
     FROM            
         Company 
     INNER JOIN
         Product ON Company.CompanyId = Product.CompanyId
     WHERE         
         (Company.GeoId LIKE moh)
    )
FROM            
    GeoLanguage
WHERE        
    (LanguageId = 1)
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'moh'.

Comment: un-hunh ... thats nice, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Are you just trying to do `where Company.GeoId like GeoId+'%'`? Your syntax looks really strange. That still doesn't really make sense if GeoId is the same field you're comparing it to.

Comment: I have a headache after working about two hour , I must to show list of cities with their count of products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT        A.GeoTitle AS Expr1,A.GeoId,
    (SELECT       count( Product.ProductId)
    FROM            Company INNER JOIN
                             Product ON Company.CompanyId = Product.CompanyId
    WHERE        (Company.GeoId LIKE A.GeoId+'%'))

    FROM            GeoLanguage as A
    WHERE        (A.LanguageId = 1)
```

Comment: Rinto Antony my skype id from india